# NInject Conventions: What happened to InRequestScope?

Tags: ninject

I've just upgraded NInject Conventions and notice that scanner.InRequestScope has gone, although it remains available in NInject 2.2.
Where has it gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ninject 2.3 is work in progress for the 2.4 version. Use 2.2!

Comment: This isn't related to perhaps using the "Noweb" version?